# Issue with SQLite query between 2 dates

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm working on a Python project which use SQlite3 database.

I created database with only one table called "Message" with this kind of data:

```
connexion = sqlite3.connect(BDD)
c = connexion.cursor()
c.execute(f""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {arg}(
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Jour_Heure_Reception text, 
    Jour_Heure_Reponse text, 
    Theme text,
    Motif text,
    Risque_incident_client text, 
    Transfert_sans_action text,
    Matricule text, 
    Origine text)""")
connexion.commit()
connexion.close();
```

My goal is to search between 2 dates in the Jour_Heure_Reponse column, and return the number of entries by matricule.

To do that, I use this SQlite query:

```
def nbr(arg):
    "requette dans la bdd de statistiques mails retournant le nombre de messages par utilisateur sur la période arg"
    #Création de la liste des utilisateurs ayant saisies des entrées dans la BDD sur la période 
    connexion = sqlite3.connect(BDD)
    c = connexion.cursor()    
    date_selection = str((datetime.now() - timedelta(arg)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
    yesterday = str(datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
    c.execute(f"""
          select Matricule from Message Where 
          Jour_Heure_Reception >= "{date_selection}" 
          and Jour_Heure_Reponse < "{yesterday}" """  )
    agents = c.fetchall() 
    liste_agents = []
    for i in agents:
        if not i[0] in liste_agents:
            liste_agents.append(i[0])
    c.close()
    # calcul du nombre d'entrées pour chaque matricules présent dans la liste crée précédemment
    connexion = sqlite3.connect(BDD)
    c = connexion.cursor()    
    liste_affichage = [] 
    for i in liste_agents:
        c.execute(f"""SELECT * FROM Message where 
              Matricule = "{i}" and 
              Jour_Heure_Reception >= "{date_selection}" and 
              Jour_Heure_Reponse < "{yesterday}" """)
        test = c.fetchall()        
        print(i)
        for i in test:
            print(i[1])
        data_list = [str(i),str(len(test))]
        liste_affichage.append(data_list)    
    c.close()
```

The problème is that one:

When i call mi nbr func, it return nothing if mi arg is not 1, and even with 1 arg, the result is not logical.

for exemple, calling nrb(1), return this ( i only print dates ):

```
02/06/2020
02/06/2020
02/06/2020
02/06/2020
02/06/2020
02/06/2020
02/06/2020
03/06/2020
03/06/2020
03/06/2020
03/06/2020
02/07/2020
02/07/2020
02/07/2020
03/07/2020
03/08/2020
02/09/2020
03/09/2020
03/09/2020
09/08/2020
09/08/2020
09/08/2020
09/08/2020
09/08/2020
01/10/2020
02/10/2020
02/10/2020
```

As you can see, the timedelta is not respected.

As the datatype is stored as Text, I send dates as str after a time.strftime() conversion.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlite does not have a dedicated date type. It supports storing date using a text field in ISO-8601 format. You will have to do date format conversion, so that you can perform your comparison. For the format details and documentation see this:
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

You should use `%Y-%m-%d` as format string.

Comment: Thank you for reply and the link. I already do conversion for yesterday and date_selection. You mean that i also have to convert the stored data ? Is this possible directible during the query ? I already tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: I wonder if the easiest and cleanest way to do this will not to creat new colums to save timestamps? With this solution, i keep those columns for display, and use timestamps to do the query.

Comment: You might do that, or have a transfomer that transfoms between the data and the storage view. Depends on the use-case. I would go with the transformer approach.